# Why Siebel IP17 Tomcat test fails for Redirect port but not for Connection port?

Tags: siebel

I'm at the stage of a migration installation for Siebel IP17 where I have just run the 2 startup.bat commands from the AI and SES contains. I can see that these are running in TaskManager.
 
I have been told I should be able to see a Tomcat screen after entering into a browser a URL with my Redirect Port (i.e. https://localhost:443 ).
 
This does not work, but my Connection Port http://localhost:8080 does.
 
I have double-checked my keystore/truststore passwords against those files and confirmed they are correct in the "server.xml" files.
 
I also tested with a short-cut for Chrome that had this path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "-ignore-certificate-errors" to ignore certificate issues.
 
This still did not help.
 
Any tips on what else to check?
 
Bryan

Answer (score 0):

What HTTPS Redirect Port did you specify when installing SES and when installing AI?

by default it says to use 443 for both, but you must install different ports ex 9011 for SES and 9001 for AI.

Also please check if your port is being blocked/used by any other service.
You can use netstat -ano|find "443" command to check which service PID is using the port.

Thanks,
Swapnil Walse.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be part of expected behaviour when OpenSSL is used or the certificate related work.